# MongoDB collection schema

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm a 1 day beginner in `MongoDB` and I try to not think the classic `relational` way, which seems pretty harder in the implementation than what I thought.

what I want to achieve is a simple database containing 2 collections : 
**User** - **Interest**

a user might have many interests.

this is what I have now :

**User :**

```
{
    _id: 'user1',
    language: 'EN', 
    firstName: 'Mehdi',
    interests: [
        interest1, 
        interest2, 
        interest3
    ]
}
```

**Interest :**

```
{
    _id: 'interest1',
    name: 'Mobile'
}
```

So I'm a little bit confused here,

should I store first store Interest documents in the Interest Collection then retrieve them as Objects and store them as `Binary Objects` in User documents ? so I will have something like : **Create Interest Documents** --> **Retrieve them**  --> **create Users document and Store the interests on it** ?

Or should I simply nest Interest documents in the User document without create them before. so I will have something like : **Create User Documents and create/nest Interests document on it** ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know your exact requirements, but I would probably use just the "users" collection, and embed interests the way you have.

If you want a list of all the different interests, you can try:

```
db.users.distinct("interests");
```

Comment: Thank you. Should I embed them as documents or as Binary Objects ?

Comment: In MongoDB, every document is stored as a binary object (BSON), but as far as it goes for a developer, thats not relevant. When you embed data, you are just adding more properties to an existing object. This are the available BSON types: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/